# xslt 2 processor that has support of exslt:evaluate()

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

In XSLT 2 style sheet

If simple boolean expression that has only 0, 1, and, or, (, ) tokens
that is contained in string variable.

Than how to get the final value of expression.
along with I need to use tokenize(), replace() function also.

Is here some xslt 2 processor that has support of exslt:evaluate() also on Ubuntu ?
Saxon, Xalan, xsltproc I tried but Xalan, xsltproc do not support tokenize() and replace().
not sure about evaluate() also.

```
<xsl:template name="test">
  <xsl:variable name="nexpression" select="myfun:getexpr()"/>
  <!-- return boolean exp   like "0 or (1 and 1) or 1" -->
  <xsl:value-of select="exslt:evaluate($nexpression)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here myfun:getexpr() return simple boolean expression.

or here **some other approch** to this boolean expression's final value.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon has an extension function saxon:evaluate() which is similar to exslt:evaluate() but differs in detail; the main difference is that it doesn't allow direct access to variables declared in the stylesheet, but does allow parameter passing instead.

Comment: saxon home edition saxon9he  and saxonb8-9.jar  do not support saxon:evaluation currently I have. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried myfn:getexpval()

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:myfn="http://whatever"
                xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">

  <xsl:function name="myfn:getexpval">
    <xsl:param name="exp"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (matches($exp, $openp) != ()) then
                            myfn:clget-simple-expval(concat(substring-before($exp, $openp),
                                                            myfn:clfoundopen(substring-after($exp, $openp))))
                          else myfn:clget-simple-expval($exp)
                          "/>

  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="myfn:clfoundopen">
    <xsl:param name="openexp"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (matches($openexp, $openp) != () and
                              functx:index-of-string-first($openexp, $openp) &lt; functx:index-of-string-first($openexp, $closep)
                             ) then
                            myfn:clget-simple-expval(concat(substring-before($openexp, $openp),
                                                            myfn:clfoundopen(substring-after($openexp, $openp))))
                          else
                            myfn:clget-simple-expval(concat(substring-before($openexp, $closep),
                                                            myfn:clfoundopen(substring-after($openexp, $closep))))
                          "/>
  </xsl:function>
  <xsl:function name="myfn:clget-simple-expval">
    <xsl:param name="exp"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ztokens" select="tokenize($exp, 'or')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="forret">
      <xsl:value-of select="some $i in $ztokens satisfies
                            myfn:cland($i) = true()"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="if ($forret = true())
                          then
                          1
                          else
                          0"/>

  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="myfn:cland">
    <xsl:param name="exp"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ztokens" select="tokenize($exp, 'and')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="forret">
      <xsl:value-of select="every $i in $ztokens satisfies
                            replace($i, ' ', '') eq '1'"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$forret"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:value-of select="myfn:getexpval('0 or ( 1 and 1 )')"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```